# jquery cycle won't pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

For some reason, the pause command for [Jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

```
$('#headerimgs').cycle('pause');
```

would not pause the image transitions and it should acording to [this link](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause.html)

Can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/r7cUb/17/

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Cycle Light plugin, seems it doesn't have pause functionality, but it works fine if I use Cycle (all) plugin.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/r7cUb/21/

Use this script

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="http://toniweb.us/gm/js/cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

for pause

```
$('#pauseButton').click(function() { 
    $('#headerimgs').cycle('pause'); 
});
```

and for resume

```
$('#resumeButton').click(function() { 
    $('#headerimgs').cycle('resume'); 
});
```

Comment: that would basically change the traditional 'onclick' for the jquery version man!